# How to use ActionBarActivity with Theme.Material

Tags: android, material-design

I created a new project targeting the L preview. The starter activity that the sdk generates extends ActionBarActivity, however, when I try to run the bare-bone generated activity, it throws the following exception:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:110)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
```

I've looked around but `Theme.AppCompat.Material` doesn't seem to exist. How do I make ActionBarActivity to take advantage of the new Material themes?

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.sdchang.example'
        minSdkVersion 'L'
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.+'
}
```

Comment: 21.+'s `Theme.AppCompat` extends `Theme.Base.AppCompat` which extends `Theme.Platform.AppCompat` which extends `android:Theme.Material` on 21+ devices (i.e., Android L) devices.

Comment: Many thanks, this solved my problem. Could you create an answer so that it is clear?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

AppCompat v21.+'s `Theme.AppCompat` extends `Theme.Base.AppCompat` which extends `Theme.Platform.AppCompat` which extends `android:Theme.Material` on 21+ devices (i.e., Android L) devices so you shouldn't have to do anything specific to get the `Material` theme if you are using AppCompat.

Comment: Just a heads up, the SDK-generated styles.xml in res/values-v21 uses @android:Theme.Material.Light. You may want to file a ticket on that.

Comment: I've been running into exactly the same issue, and I am going to try your proposed answer now. But would like to point out that google's docs at https://developer.android.com/preview/material/compatibility.html do specifically say we should a have separate parent theme in the values-21 folder...

Comment: Confirmed: just use the AppCompat theme and on v21 you will get Material. I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and traced its parents to Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar for v21+. However in the emulator my actionbar isn't actually dark, but this is a preview after all. The parent structure is sound and this answer is correct.

Comment: Even though the sdk is following the docs correctly, personally I think it is a bug when the sdk generates a project that crashes at runtime. :(

Comment: To clarify Google are aware of this as a bug and a fix is awaiting approval for the next release. https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/112723/

Answer (score 3):

You need to change dependency in the build gradle to

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not it. 21.+ is already the default generated by the SDK.

Comment: Do you have compileSdkVersion 'android-L'? Can you please provide your gradle.build?

Comment: Can you try use 'android-L' instead of 'L'?

Answer (score -1):

Use the following Theme:

```
android:theme="@style/Base.V7.Theme.AppCompat" >
```

Comment: That must be android:theme="@style/stylename" and the appcompat_v7 library must be linked with the project. And in styles.xml the parent must be  parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" or of your choice

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ManishDubey Sure looks like an answer to me.