# Android error for `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light`

Tags: android, styles, material-design

Hi I am building one android sample application with some material design concepts. I started with https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html. I am using eclipse. I have added appcompat_7 support library in library section of my project.Then When I try to apply following theme.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">

</style>
```

It gives me following run time error:

```
11-12 11:32:30.416: E/AndroidRuntime(21375): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
 ComponentInfo{com.example.androidmaterialdesignapi/com.example.androidmaterialdesignapi.MainActivity}: 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

My activity extends `ActionBarActivity`. Am I doing anything wrong. Need some help. Thank you. Is there any good example to learn material design?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545394/how-to-use-actionbaractivity-with-theme-material](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545394/how-to-use-actionbaractivity-with-theme-material)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes when you use ActionBar activity as parent activity you need to have Theme.AppCompat as your parent style for your customized theme.

Replace your line as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

instead of this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: and @M D thank you for quick replay. it solves my issue. Thank you. Any one have any good sample code for learning material design. I tried to I/O 2014 application code but that also fails.

Comment: but why it is not accepting "@android:style/Theme.Material.Light". Any idea