# Can't use ActionBarActivity with Theme.Material

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Whenever I extend the class with `ActionBarActivity` it generates a runtime error on the emulator when I am using the theme as Theme.Material... in the styles. When I change this theme to AppCompat it works fine. Or Even if I change the `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity` with the theme as Theme.Material then also it works fine on the Lollipop emulator.

`styles/values-v1.xml`:

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#3F51B5</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#3031B5</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#f00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#00f</item>
</style>
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.sharmakritya.myapplication;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


         }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if(id==R.id.next){

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

`build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sharmakritya.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3"
}
```

I want to use the `ActionBar` with the Material theme on the Lollipop. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `Theme.Material` on Android 5.0+, those activities that use that theme need to be ordinary activities using the native action bar, and you will need to have some other theme for older devices that is based off of `Theme.Holo`.

If you want to use `ActionBarActivity` from `appcompat-v7`, you have to use `Theme.AppCompat` as the basis for your theme, and rely upon it to give you a Material Design-ish on old and new devices.

So, to recap:

- `Theme.Material` requires the native action bar
- the `appcompat-v7` action bar backport cannot use `Theme.Material`

Comment: So you mean to say that if I use the Theme.Material I cant use ActionBarActivity ?

Comment: I am following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMO8EVkhJO8&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=3 and basically copied the code from this tutorial and he does use the Theme.Material and still extend the ActionBarActivity

Comment: There must be a work around to it because I have seen others app do this too ? Also, have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24545804/632316 According to it should work.

Comment: @kritya: "he does use the Theme.Material" -- not according to the video's description ("You need to use a Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar or Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar to prevent the default action bar from displaying."). "There must be a work around to it because I have seen others app do this too ?" -- feel free to provide a link to a Java project that implements it. Considering that [the guy who wrote `appcompat-v7` says that you need `Theme.AppCompat`](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/), your claims require better proof.

Comment: Considering that, the answer I linked you to as it says the Material theme extends AppCompat, according to it , using Material theme must mean using AppCompat theme. Am I right till here ? Which to my small knowledge of this should mean that if I use Material Theme I am also using the AppCompat theme's properties. Correct me pls if I am wrong

Comment: @kritya: "the Material theme extends AppCompat" -- `Theme.Material` does not extend from `Theme.AppCompat`. `Theme.Material` is part of the standard Android SDK. `Theme.AppCompat` comes from the `appcompat-v7` library. You can use `Theme.Material` without any reference to `appcompat-v7`, as you can see in [this set of samples from my book](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/BasicMaterial). Hence, it is not possible for `Theme.Material` to extend `Theme.AppCompat`. "Am I right till here ?" -- no, sorry.

Comment: Getting back to the video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMO8EVkhJO8&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD&index=3 at [b]10:15[/b] it does looks like material theme to me, while he is still using setSupportActionBar() which you can see at 10:23

Comment: @kritya: At the 10:15 mark, there is no code fully visible, as it is obscured by a pair of emulators. My guess, therefore, as that by "looks like material theme", you mean the emulators. As I wrote in my answer, `appcompat-v7` will give you a look and feel that resembles Material Design. What you are seeing in those emulators can easily be the `appcompat-v7`, `Theme.AppCompat` look. [These sample projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat) demonstrate the use of `Theme.AppCompat`.

Comment: Okay. I get most of it now. But as you said it can be made to look like Theme.Material. How ? P.s. Github is blocked here.

Comment: @kritya: "But as you said it can be made to look like Theme.Material" -- no, I said that it *does* resemble `Theme.Material`. "How ?" -- just use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your main activity must extends ActionBarActivity

`public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {`

Comment: Yea that's what I mean to say. Whenever I use that it gives me a run time error

Comment: Sorry, but since I just started using Android Studio, The logcat window is in always empty. All I can tell is on the emulator it says MyApp has stopped working.

Comment: Hum not simple without log... Remove your theming from manifest

Comment: As I have already quoted in the question. It does work with AppCompat theme. I need to use it with Material theme